# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space obtained when creating JTable with 41000 rows

Tags: java, jtable, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to create a JTable that shows 41000 rows of data, I had the same code working fine for another JTable that I needed to create with only 4457 rows so my problem does not come from the data. My program execution takes 25 minutes to compute all the values that need to be shown in my user interface. Once the program execution finishes, I receive the following error message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.convertToVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.convertToVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(Unknown Source)"
```

Is it impossible to create a JTable with 41000 rows? Is that too large for the JTable to be created? I don't think that something is wrong with my program since I had the same code working fine for another table made of 4457 rows.

Comment: Some **core** code? Please +:

Comment: You need to make sure you have enough memory allocated to your JVM for this to work properly. And maybe can you look for some improvment on your code to reduce a bit memory usage

Comment: Set -Xmx2048m in JVM variebles of your project properties.

Comment: I don't understand your assumption. You say "the data is not the problem because it worked when I tried it with only 10% of the amount of data". Now you use 41000 rows and you run out of memory. So the simple guess is: it's too much data for your current memory configuration.

Comment: Why would you need to display all of that rows in the first place

Comment: I am reading a database, making some computations and diplaying the values of my computations in a JTable

Comment: Imagine each row takes up 100kb in memory. With 4400 rows, that takes up 430mb of memory already. 41000rows, roughly ten times as much, takes up 4.3gb of memory. If that's above what your JVM allows, you get an OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4457  != 41000**. It's obviuos that it depends in your object side.

> Is it impossible to create a JTable with 41000 rows?

It all depends in the Object that you are rendering. It's differnt an object with only 1 field that an object that more. It depends in your JVM configuration as the comments said, adding more memory can be a solution  `-Xmx2048m`

> Is that too many rows for the JTable to be created?

The same answer. It depends of the type of Objects you are using. If the object is too large it can better to use Pagination or make a better approach for this.

Comment: I am using the same object type that I used for my other table that was made of 4000 rows and that works perfeclty fine. I am just providing a bigger source of input to my program and the size of the table ends up being 41000 rows but the object nature is the same

Comment: I know is the same Object but is different an List of size 4000 and a list of size of 41000. It consumes more memory in the end. Check with a Profiler to see what is the limit size in your current configuration settings